# Notification not received when location is updated

Tags: swift, notifications

I created a notification that will be sent when a location update is available:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        // If we don't have a valid location, exit
        guard let location = locations.first where (location.horizontalAccuracy <= 20 || location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow < 5 ) else {
            return
        }

        // or if we already have searched, return
        guard !didPerformGeocode else {
            return
        }

        // otherwise, update state variable, stop location services and start geocode
        self.didPerformGeocode = true

        // Set current user location
        currentUserLocation = location

        // Send notification about changed location
        notificationCenter.postNotificationName("LOCATION_AVAILABLE", object: nil, userInfo: ["location":self.currentUserLocation!])

        // Stop location search before geocode
        self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.geocodeLocation(location)
    }
```

I want to receive this notification in my tableViewController:

```
class AEDTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Notifications
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

    // MARK: - Location
    var currentLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation()

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "aedListReceived:", name: "AED_LIST_UPDATED", object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "locationAvailable:", name: "LOCATION_AVAILABLE", object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func locationAvailable(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        self.currentLocation = userInfo["location"] as! CLLocation
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

But the notification is never being received even though I see updated locations. When I want to debug this, I see that it never calls the method mentioned in the notificationObserver.

Comment: Are you sure your notification observers are setup by the time you send out the notification?

Comment: hm.. good point... the tableviewcontroller only gets loaded, when I hit a button on a previous screen as this is not the rootView. How do I setup the notification then?

Comment: The easiest way to go about is to store your location somewhere (I tend to go for a singleton) and reference that location in your view controllers.